# Image doesn't show on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, mobile

I was making my website and want to test it on my phone but all the images in my website does not show when I'm testing on my mobile phone.

The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>KTWebsite</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="help">
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AIhWLmgTANP66HiMCypZ46ZLY86hnHzCGWsSR-THeG_jVoZspsxBfPsYm7ZmPLStl6K4o_oZi5lw3mWaAn5sEGdNMAQrElK5zqnxzd-znxL_pjwyJoKsX0xv0ZFt0scNv-AuPD5vcNZhcZc4zDe9hxvWGNn2nCJWj1fgIUSQEt54qYObsScfkeLcriASDVda0EvWpWqJ3-TZ5aORLu2b5oo6_VU7ORxzcn9p6iWnOc40AvXsdDV03AJ8p7_NY5AZn8lHGubA73rdR-IXDPMB6CdHXfR4pjPGCwiqbM4SVHQhLwEF3Eun_b1lH4nWhFYp8YjDjwH69Z5RfaSQCbSQ1EqEiGZ0dQNnie4pFwWn31xbl8OPRDJeFwllo8vTu42END-swg_He3J27U2v2VsE1xCGaVCtxyLpFHq28s_bipFE3nO3B6VDUTzf9PQKa9s40dLVV8oKyc-hA4BXsVATIrqN_tJcr1vqkJsX_zTCAyksjIDw8yII8RdAMDzMR00-T0_yjigLuxjM8irqoaGhp0acZzVBm8eelPbKYhVxwPFSQlqZODU-BL4bwmtwAvaA6lzAlE3k1RfRnWdO2An3QfS4aDc_YjwbBL78a3tdtz1tJdrp6Y3oGiR3TulxS4QZ1BlO5L-CyDCY7FP-89pQSrf8awWJZNaTewKadyTsmjERqEAFuNsHWsDnlUNj4beL7dQ6OY1TYEhTpceWSYNx-KQ=w558-h590-no?authuser=0" width=35 height="35">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ths is not a full answer because I do not know enough about the google system.

However, to note in case this helps:

I saw the image using the code given in the question on my laptop.

I then tried the code on an iOS device and didn't see it.

I tried just putting the address in the browser address bar and saw the image on my laptop but not on the IOS device. I then logged into a google account on my laptop and saw the image (when its address was in the address bar of the browser).

I tried your code again on the IOS device and still didn't see the image.

On my laptop I logged out of my google account and then tried your code. This time I did not see the image.

So, there is something about needing to be logged into a google account to see that image, and even then it's not enough from the img element code on IOS.